# What is the best Scheme interpreter or compiler?

Tags: scheme

Hey everyone, I want to start using Scheme and I have two questions.  First, would you recommend using an interpreter or a compiler for Scheme and why?  Second, which interpreter or compiler for Scheme would you recommend and why?  Thanks!

Comment: My question was a little different then those, but thanks!

Comment: BTW, as a "what is the best" question without clarifying details, this one seems awfully subjective. If there was agreement on a single best scheme implementations (for all purposes and use cases), we'd only have one!

Comment: Definitely a constructive question, people with more rep than me should re-open this

Answer (score 32, accepted):

For a beginner, I would highly recommend [DrRacket](http://docs.racket-lang.org/drracket/)  (formerly Dr. Scheme), since it gives you a really nice environment to work in, supports many dialects of Scheme, and gives very good failure and debugging information. I believe most implementations of Scheme are interpreters, although it is possible that there is a compiler out there.

If you are a commandline junkie like me, an alternative you might consider is to run the [racket](http://racket-lang.org) interpreter directly, which is essentially the same thing as Dr. Racket, but without the graphical environment and a commandline interface. Or, start your source file with `#! /usr/bin/env racket` and make it executable with `chmod +x source.rkt`.

Comment: Dr. Scheme is one of the most complete interpreters I have used.  Very useful for beginners who get stuck at the command line and cannot translate the cryptic error messages into where the code is wrong.

Comment: Actually there more big-name Scheme compilers than interpreters: ikarus, chez (the non-free version), gambit, chicken, bigloo. In fact mzscheme/DrScheme is JITted in current versions. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category:Scheme_compilers

Comment: I am a command-line junkie too, I have been using Dr. Scheme a bit, but I will give mzscheme a try too. I've also been using gambit-c a little too, any thoughts on that?

Answer (score 32):

I know  you already accepted the answer, but for future visitors to this question, I recommend [Chicken Scheme](http://www.call-cc.org/). It tends to produce *much* smaller executables than mzscheme does. Take the following hello world application, for instance:

```
(define (say-hello name)
  (print (string-append "Hello, " name))
  (newline))

(say-hello "Earthling")
```

Compiled with mzc --exec mztest hello.scm: 3.3M

Compiled with csc hello.scm -o ctest: 16k

And if you're after library support, Chicken provides [Eggs Unlimited](http://chicken.wiki.br/chicken-projects/egg-index-4.html), which is like PlaneT for mzscheme (or gems for ruby).

Comment: Chicken owns. I actually get to use it for real work, too. And don't forget about Gambit-C, either.

Comment: AFAIK mzscheme creates an statically linked executable, whereas chicken scheme's dynamically linked against libchicken.

Comment: That's right, try to run that 16k file in your platform without Chicken Scheme. It is dynamically linked.

Comment: With the option `-static`, you can also get a statically-linked executable from the chicken compiler.  For `mzc`, a `#lang scheme` declaration needs to be added at the beginning of the source.  Then `mzc --exe mztest hello.scm` gives a 4.6M executable.  While `csc hello.scm -o cktest` gives a 3.2M executable.

Comment: I use to love chicken schem but lately a lot of my software keeps breaking and i dont like that. I Would really say stick to racket. Stuff doesnt break when they move.

Answer (score 11):

I'd recommend [Gambit-C](http://gambitscheme.org/wiki/index.php/Main_Page) scheme:

- It's R5RS-conformant.
- It has both an interpreter and a compiler. You can also compile to ANSI C.
- It's open source.
- It's portable. (It runs on Linux, Windows, Mac OS X and even iOS.)
- It has simple foreign function interfaces (FFI).

A cursory examination reveals that Chicken seems unsatisfactory, while Bigloo may be a serious contender. But I cannot comment too much about them.

Comment: What did you find unsatisfactory about Chicken Scheme?

Comment: Can't answer for the OP, but in the small number of (as always, completely meaningless) benchmarks I tried when choosing which one to use recently, Gambit absolutely owned Chicken for performance. It seemed like Gambit was better than twice as fast on average. Chicken's GC was also a *lot* slower, like ten times or something.

Answer (score 10):

I'd recommend not being concerned about whether it's implemented as a compiler, interpreter, or combination thereof -- especially to start with, the quality of help files (for one example) will matter far more than exactly how it's implemented.

As far as which one, [DrRacket](https://racket-lang.org/) is what I use (by far) the most often.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I'm using PLT Scheme and I like it a lot.

Comment: It is called racket today.

Comment: @vonbrand: Yeah, definitely overdue for an update...

Answer (score 6):

PTL Scheme has been renamed to Racket (http://racket-lang.org/), but it's still pretty much the same. Dr. Racket is a very nifty development environment with a shell, and to write in Scheme all you need is `#lang scheme` at the top of your file.